# How can I change a router's factory settings?

Tags: router, wireless-router

I would like to know if there is a way for me to change a router's default settings. When I say that I don't mean logging in the page setup and configuring it. What I mean is to change the settings that the router will be after you reset it (Even if it means brute-forcing my way there).

Comment: I think the question is, "How do I lock my router so the settings cannot be changed".

Comment: Any concrete router you're looking at or just a hypothetical question?

Comment: +I think the question is, "How do I lock my router so the settings cannot be changed"
   -Not really. It can still be changed. I just want it to have different settings when I reset it, since physical access to it is complicated.

+Any concrete router you're looking at or just a hypothetical question?
   -I'm currently trying to do this on a WRT160Nv2 (It doesn't support DD-WRT, unfortunately...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The factory settings are stored in the firmware. So you have to flash the router with a custom firmware.

But first, you have to find where those settings are into the firmware.
Note some routers have a "security" against modified firmwares.

In short: you can't, except if you have lots of free time